# Как отловить нужный сетевой пакет

Tags: delphi, клиент-сервер, сниффер

Имеем любую флеш игру, которая общается со своим сервером.

При подключении к серверу он выделяет клиенту `SessionID` или какой-то другой 
`UID`, которого достаточно, чтобы запросить какие-то данные о игроке у сервера и который при каждом новом входе в игру меняется.

Как на Delphi перехватить этот пакет и вытащить данный `ID`?

Т.е. на данный момент запускаю любой сниффер, смотрю там нужную мне информацию (`ID`), вставляю в свою программу и она дальше исправно работает, при следующем старте всё заново... Хотелось бы научить её делать это самостаятельно.

Comment: как минимум два варианта - либо Ваше приложение стает проксей для игры (в этом случае все тривиально), либо используете библиотеку pcap.

Comment: @KoVadim, а оба случая более подробно можно? Я не представляю как моё приложение может стать проксей для онлайн флеш игры. С WinPCap из Delphi тоже не имел чести работать

Comment: Поставил http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/magmonsock.asp
 ловлю я нужные пакеты через `WinPcap`, через то самое единственное событие в `TMonitorPCap` - `OnPacketEvent` но нигде не могу найти `SequenceNr` пакета и их количество, принадлежащее одному ответу, чтобы собрать из нескольких пакетов 1 файл. Может кто подсказать куда смотреть?